# How to use the any function in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have written something like this

```
gameOver :: Board -> Bool
gameOver testboard
= any checksingle ( nub (rows testboard))
  where 
    checksingle :: [Cell] -> Bool
    checksingle [a] 
      | [a] == [Empty] = False
      | otherwise = True
    checksingle _
      = False
```

Here rows will return [[Cell]]

What I am trying to do is Map (nub to rows testboard), which I tested and works, and the result of this should still be [[Cell]]. Then I tried to apply Map checksingle (the list above) so each [Cell] gets will applied to checksingle and finally I try to see if any results is true. Haskero told me that True `elem` Map (checksingle.nub) (rows testboard) is same as any checksingle ( nub (rows testboard)) but neither option will work.

Comment: Exactly what is the problem/error/... you receive?

Comment: It is not clear to me why you use `nub`, since regardless whether you check unique rows or not, in both cases. these will return the same result.

Comment: (And `nub` is much more expensive per element than `checkSingle`.)